# DateTimeFormField and TextFormField don't match Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

**Time First Seen** is a `DateTimeFormField` and others are all `TextFormField`, they have similar padding and everything but the `labelText` of `DateTimeFormField` is smaller and more contrasty than of the `TextFormField`, how can I make them look similar?

Also I've used   `date_field: ^1.0.5` dependency to achieve this, tried using others but all of them had the same result.

[image]

**Here's my code for the two:**

```
TextFormField(
                    onSaved: null,
                    controller: _ipCountryCode,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'IP Country Code',
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: DateTimeFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              labelText: 'Time First Seen',
                              fillColor: Colors.white,
                              filled: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8)),
                          onDateSelected: (DateTime value) {
                            setState(() {
                              timeFirstSeen = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Comment: This is something to discuss with the developers of the package that you used. consider filing an issue at the respective repo: https://github.com/GaspardMerten/date_field/issues

Comment: thank you, I will do that but in the mean time could you suggest me any other package or way to achieve this?

Comment: I suppose inputDecoration takes a labelstyle: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/InputDecoration.html you could try to replicate the TextFormField's default style by overriding the DateTimeFormField's default style

Comment: I will fix this today!